# Assign every user a role on a Discord Server with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'd like to add a role to every user on a Discord Server. I am using "discord.js". I know how to assign a role to a specific user, but I do not know how to do the same thing to every user.

Here is my current code:

```
//defines the role to a variable
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "myRole");
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I dno exactly how discord works, but try to find how they return all users and simply use `Array#Map` method:

listOfAllUsers.map(user => ({ ...user, role: "myRole" }))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to loop through each member of the guild and add the respective role.

```
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "myRole"); // Getting the role
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => { // Looping through each member.
    member.roles.add(role); // Adding the role.
});
```